# How can I end interval without unsubscribing in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have database queries that get executed and return data from the server. When the data returns my subscription works. If I call `refreshData` the queries execute again and return data, however the subscription in `AnotherComponent` doesn't run the second time.

I believe that this is caused by `take(1)` which is taking one item and ending the subscription. Is there a way that I can end the interval, but keep the subscription active in `AnotherComponent`?

**Note:** I decided to use an interval because some items subscribe too late and never receive the initial data.

I don't think that a `ReplaySubject` is the way to go because I don't care what the previous data was.

This service makes the applications initial queries needed to load a page.

```js
export class StartupGraphqlService {

  private initCalled = false;
  private queryResults?: StartupCompletion;

  private readonly startupQueries = new Subject<StartupCompletion>();

  get $startupQueries() {
    return interval(100)
      .pipe(
        filter(() => !!this.queryResults),
        map(() => this.queryResults as StartupCompletion),
        take(1)
      );
  }

  refreshData() {
    this.initCalled = false;
    this.initQueries();
  }

  initQueries() {
    if (this.initCalled) return;
    this.initCalled = true;
    // Execute queries
    // ...
    this.startupQueries.next(data)
  }
}
```

This component executes the initial query then 3 seconds later (for testing) executes it again.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.loggedIn().subscribe(logged => {
      if(logged) {
        this.startupQueries.initQueries();
        timer(3000).subscribe(() => {
          console.log('Refresh Queries');
          this.startupQueries.refreshData();
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should display the result every time it is updated.

```
export class AnotherComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.startup.$startupQueries.subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know all the app requirements but if you are doing all of this just because of the late subscribers, you could use a `BehaviorSubject` instead of a plain `Subject` and you can ditch the _interval hack_

Comment: does initQueries perform http requests?

Comment: @Yogi yes it does using `apollo`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn you said "I decided to use an interval because some items subscribe too late and never receive the initial data.", does multiple components subscribe to `this.startup.$startupQueries`?

Comment: Yeah they do, the `AnotherComponent` is one of them

Comment: @akotech It looks like your method is working...

Comment: Just apart from the question... Why do you need to take only once, if you need to refresh the data by an interval of 100ms?

Comment: @FatihErsoy I am using an interval to test to see if data exists if not it tests again in 100ms until the data is there then stops.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using a `BehaviorSubject` works, it seems to be doing what I intended.

```js
  private queryResults?: StartupCompletion;
  private readonly startupQueries = new BehaviorSubject<StartupCompletion | undefined>(this.queryResults);
  $startupQueries = this.startupQueries.asObservable().pipe(
    filter(() => !!this.queryResults),
    map(() => this.queryResults as StartupCompletion),
  );
```